# How to demote all headings by 1?

Tags: org-mode

Given an outline with arbitrary structure, how can one demote every single heading by one?

For example, starting from something like this

```
* Lorem ips
  um dolor sit ame
** t, consectetur a
   dipiscing elit. Vivamus ph
*** aretra diam lorem, e
** u consectetur urna m
   - alesuada sit amet. Donec turpis lacus, molestie id nunc et, laoreet
   - cursus ex Integer porttitor nisl neque, id f ermentum erat tincidun
   - t sit amet. Etiam in d
*** ignissim quam. D
* onec non
```

...what's the easiest way to get to this:

```
** Lorem ips
   um dolor sit ame
*** t, consectetur a
    dipiscing elit. Vivamus ph
**** aretra diam lorem, e
*** u consectetur urna m
    - alesuada sit amet. Donec turpis lacus, molestie id nunc et, laoreet
    - cursus ex Integer porttitor nisl neque, id f ermentum erat tincidun
    - t sit amet. Etiam in d
**** ignissim quam. D
** onec non
```

Of course, after this global demotion I'd add a new top-level header encompassing all the demoted headers in its subtree.

Comment: @lawlist I think you mean selecting all and pressing alt-right-arrow. (This addresses a deleted comment.)

Comment: @Tobias -- I was thinking of meta-shift-arrow (instead of shift-arrow) with a selected region, but my preliminary test after I posted a comment showed it only affected a portion of the original poster's test code, so I deleted the comment . . . [I understood the question to mean everything in one fell swoop, and my initial idea only affected the first main heading and every sub-heading underneath, but not subsequent main headings and subtrees.]

Comment: @lawlist alt-right-arrow does that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`org-do-demote` will demote everything within a marked region.  According to the docstring:

> `(org-do-demote)`
>
> Demote the current heading lower down the tree.
>   If the region is active in `transient-mark-mode`, demote all headings
>   in the region.

So: mark the region and `org-do-demote`.  In practice, you can use `org-mataright` in this situation, which will demote the subtree.

Alternately, you can simply use `org-demote-subtree`:

> `org-demote-subtree` is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `org.el`.
>
> `(org-demote-subtree)`
>
> Demote the entire subtree.  See `org-do-demote`.
>   See also `org-do-promote`.

`org-demote-subtree` is bound to `M-S-<right>`.